# How can i add objHoles to each obj?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to add arrHoles to each arrPlayers. arrHoles can be from 0-20 objects inside.

Any easy way to do this?

Im new to javascript if there is somthing wrong in the code i want some feedback :D

```
   let players = document.querySelectorAll('#players div');
    let holes = document.getElementById('holes');
    let arrPlayers = [];
    let arrHoles = [];
    for (let a = 0; a < holes.length; a++) {
        arrHoles.push({
            win: false,
            lose: false,
            push: false,
            points: "2"
        });

    }
    console.log(arrHoles);
    players.forEach(function(index, value) {
        //Legger til alle spillere
        arrPlayers.push({
            /*I WANT this EACH PLAYER GET THIS FOR EACH HOLE*/
            /*holes: [{
                win: false,
                lose: false,
                push: false,
                points: "2"
            }],*/
            name: players[value].childNodes[0].data,
            id: players[value].getAttribute("data-id")
        });
        //arrPlayers[value];
        //arrPlayers.push(arrHoles);
    });
```

Comment: Depends: do you want the same data for each player, or does each player need their own copy?

Comment: Same data for each player.

Comment: Then just have a `holes` property with the `arrHoles` array. Focus on getting things working, then focus on how a "real" JS dev would do it. You'll learn more that way.

Comment: I think each player need there own copy.  Because they need to be able to change status for each holes.

Comment: Then you'd need a deep copy for each player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function that returns the array you need, and then call it for each player:

```
function getHoles() {
    let holes = document.getElementById('holes');
    let arrHoles = [];
    for (let a = 0; a < holes.length; a++) {
        arrHoles.push({
            win: false,
            lose: false,
            push: false,
            points: "2"
        });
    }
    return arrHoles
}
```

Then call it when you create your players:

```
...
arrPlayers.push({
   holes: getHoles(),
   name: players[value].childNodes[0].data,
   id: players[value].getAttribute("data-id")
});
...
```